# Ruby on rails application - trying to convert some processing from server side to client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, client-side, server-side

Trying to simplify oiginal question below.

How do I use Json/Javascript/Coffeeescript to send values from the screen partial (_evaluation_assumptions.html.erb) to the assumptions in the services (services/evaluation/assumption.rb) using the apps/assets/javascripts/drills.js.coffee

---

I am trying to convert some Ruby on Rails processing from server side to client side.

Currently a user can make an estimate about the amount of oil/gas a drill will produce and then see how this effects the companies involved.  They enter their estimation amounts on a screen and then are presented with the possible results e.g he "Evaluation_Assumptions" and "Results" screen.

I am trying to change this so both screens are on the same page and changing any of the assumptions automatically re-evaluates the possible results.

I include below the Drills Controller, the View, parts of the evaluation module, the view partial, and what I have done so far in the App/assets/javascript file.

I appreciate there is more than just a one or two line correction needed so any help of any kind would be appreciated - I am not expecting a "total" solution.
- and again any help appreciated.

thanks 
Pierre

the Drills Controller
Problem 1
The "evaluation" code the  first line produces the following run time error
"Required parameter missing: evaluation_assumption"
I can't seem to get the evaluation assumptions into the Services module

```
require 'evaluation'

class DrillsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user
  before_filter :load_drill, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_filter :load_drill_interest, only: [:edit, :update, :evaluate]
  before_filter :load_resource_estimation, only: [:edit, :update, :evaluate]
  before_filter :load_user_positions, only:[:evaluate]

  authorize_resource

  rescue_from GeoPosition::Error::InvalidDegreesError,
              GeoPosition::Error::InvalidMinutesError,
               GeoPosition::Error::InvalidSecondsError do |e|
    flash[:message] = e.message
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def evaluate

    evaluation_assumption = Evaluation.generate_projection(assumption_params)
    if evaluation_assumption.valid?
      result_list = Evaluation.generate_projection(@drill.drill_interests,
                                                   evaluation_assumption)
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: results_list}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: []}
      end
    end

  end
```

The Services code which does the evaluation

Services
  Evaluation
    assumption.rb (see below)
    calculate_results.rb
    result.rb
  evaluation.rb (see below)

Evaluation/assumption.rb

```
class Evaluation
  class Assumption

    include ActiveAttr::Model

    attribute :resource_estimation_oil, type: Float
    attribute :in_ground_value_oil, type: Float
    attribute :resource_estimation_gas, type: Float
    attribute :in_ground_value_gas, type: Float
    attribute :probability_of_success, type: Integer

    validates :resource_estimation_oil, presence: true, 
              :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
    validates :in_ground_value_oil, presence: true,
              :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
    validates :resource_estimation_gas, presence: true,
              :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
    validates :in_ground_value_gas, presence: true,
              :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
    validates :probability_of_success, presence: true, 
              :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100 }

  end
end
```

evaluation.rb

```
require_relative './evaluation/assumption'
require_relative './evaluation/calculate_results'
require_relative './evaluation/result'

class Evaluation
    def self.generate_projection(drill_interests, assumption_params)
    result_list = []

    evaluation_assumption = Assumption.new(assumption_params)
    if evaluation_assumption.valid?
        drill_interests.each do |drill_interest|
          listings = drill_interest.company.company_listings
          result_list += CalculateResults.new(drill_interest,listings,evaluation_assumption).results
       end
       result_list.sort_by! {|u| u.leverage}
    end
    result_list
  end
end
```

The screens (main screen and partials for evaluation assumptions and results.

evaluate.html.erb

```
<% content_for :title, "Drill Investor - Valuations" %>
<% content_for :tab_group, "drills" %>
<% content_for :tab_id, 'Investor Room' %>
<%= content_tag :div, class: "breadcrumbs" do %>
   <%= link_to 'Drills', drill_stakes_path %> &raquo; 
  <%= @drill.name %>
<% end %>

<section>
  <article class="single">
    <div>
      <span>valuation</span>
      <select name="valuation" id="valuation" size="1">
        <option value="option1">Default</option>
        <option value="option1">User Save Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <%= render 'evaluation_assumptions' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <%= render 'evaluation_results' %> 
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <%= render 'user_positions/display_multiple' %>
    </div>

  </article>
</section>
```

the partial for evaluation_assumptions
_evaluation_assumptions.htnl.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :evaluation_assumption,
      :html => { class: 'infogroup' },
      :validate => true do |f| %>   
  <%= content_tag :header, "Assumptions", class: 'infogroup-header'%>  
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'infogroup-body' do %> 

    <%= content_tag :table, class: 'info', border: 0, cellspacing: 0, cellpadding: 0 do %>    
      <%= f.hidden_field :drill_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :member_profile_id %>
      <tr>   
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Target"), class: 'column' %>  
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Discovery Target"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Potential Resource size"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "In-Ground Value"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Probability of Success"), class: 'column' %>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, @temp_var,  
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'column' %>

      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Oil"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "p50"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, f.text_field(:resource_estimation_oil,  
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'data' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "mmbbl"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, f.text_field(:in_ground_value_oil, 
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'data' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, f.text_field(:probability_of_success, 
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'data' %>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, ""), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "Gas"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "p50"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, f.text_field(:resource_estimation_gas, 
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'data' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, content_tag(:span, "bcf"), class: 'column' %>
      <%= content_tag :td, f.text_field(:in_ground_value_gas, 
                  class: "general ralign"), class: 'data' %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>   
...
```

the results screen
_evaluation_results.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :evaluation_assumption,
      :html => { class: 'infogroup', :method => :post } do |f| %>
  <%= content_tag :header, "Results", class: 'infogroup-header'%>  
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'infogroup-body' do %> 
    <%= content_tag :table, class: 'info', border: 0, cellspacing: 5, cellpadding: 0 do %>     
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>SP</th>
        <th>Mkt Cap</th>
        <th>Discovery Value</th>
        <th>DV/Share</th>
        <th>Leverage</th>
        <th>Risked Lev </th>
        <th>Leverage with CFD's</th>
      </tr>
      <% @result_list.each do |result| %>                 
        <tr>
           <td><%= result.listing_name %></td>
           <td><%= number_to_currency(result.listing.share_price_dollars,
                  :precision => 3, :delimiter => ',')     %></td>
…
```

The javascript
Here I can get data to the screen (currently just using hard coded data as opposed to getting data from database).  What I can't do is put this data into the Services Assumptions.  How do I do this ?
drills.js.coffee

```
loadEvaluationResults = (drill_id)->
  $.getJSON "/drills/#{drill_id}/evaluate.js", $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize(),   (data,status,xhr)->
  # ('/drills/1/evaluate.json',{type:"post", data: $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()});
  # fill in table
  #    load new page from drills - evaluation

$('document').ready ->
  if $('#evaluation_assumption_params').length == 1  
     # load in some assumptions - this will be replaced by getting correct assumptions
     $('#assumption_params_resource_estimation_oil').val('1.106')
     $('#assumption_params_in_ground_value_oil').val('4')
     $('#assumption_params_resource_estimation_gas').val('0')
     $('#assumption_params_in_ground_value_gas').val('1')
     $('#assumption_params_probability_of_success').val('20')      
     # this not working to get standard values for this drill
   $('#evaluation_assumption_params').change((event) ->
         assid = $('#valuation').val()
         loadAssumption assid
     )
```

Comment: What you're asking seem kind of vague. Can you boil it down to a more specific question?

Comment: Toooo long, can you summarise?

Comment: Hi.                                                                  To simplify.  How do I use Json/Javascript/Coffeeescript to send values from the screen partial (_evaluation_assumptions.html.erb) to the assumptions in the services  (services/evaluation/assumption.rb) using the apps/assets/javascripts/drills.js.coffee.  Thanks